# How to clear the system clipboard in Java?

Tags: java, clipboard

How can I clear the `System Clipboard` in Java? I have tried

```
Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getSystemClipboard().setContents(null, null);
```

but it just had thrown an `NPE`:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException: contents
    at sun.awt.datatransfer.SunClipboard.setContents(SunClipboard.java:98)
```

Comment: [`Clipboard` docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/datatransfer/Clipboard.html). Note that `.setContents()` doesn't take `String`s. You might want to only pass the first arg (the contents) as `null`, and somehow get the `Clipboard`'s owner and pass that as the second arg?

Comment: @ajp15243 No, you're wrong. I can't pass first argument as null, but can second one.

Comment: Well, sorry for the suggestion...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can create a special `Transferable` that explicitly contains no data, as detailed [in this blog post](http://www.jroller.com/alexRuiz/entry/clearing_the_system_clipboard):

```
  clipboard.setContents(new Transferable() {
    public DataFlavor[] getTransferDataFlavors() {
      return new DataFlavor[0];
    }

    public boolean isDataFlavorSupported(DataFlavor flavor) {
      return false;
    }

    public Object getTransferData(DataFlavor flavor) throws UnsupportedFlavorException {
      throw new UnsupportedFlavorException(flavor);
    }
```

Comment: Thanks, seems to be true :)

Comment: pain in the ass. come on java.

Comment: Dealing with the clipboard is rarely a simple task, in any language. Mostly because the clipboard can hold any number of different formats at any time. It's the complexity of drag & drop, just a little more horrible.

Answer (score 6):

You can do this:

```
StringSelection stringSelection = new StringSelection("");
Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getSystemClipboard().setContents(
            stringSelection, null);
```

Since `StringSelection implements Transferable`

```
public class StringSelection implements Transferable, ClipboardOwner
```

Comment: That would set the clipboard contents to an empty string, I guess, not empty the clipboard.

Comment: @Joey Well, the important question is whether this has the desired effect. Like, if you can't set clipboard contents to nothing, what are the clipboard contents of a "clean" clipboard? (After a system is rebooted maybe.)

Comment: @millimoose: Well, an empty clipboard contains no data at all, i.e. whenever a program queries whether there is data in the clipboard in some format it might understand the answer would be »no«. For an empty string there *is* data in the clipboard, as plain text, even though this data has length 0. Programs might opt to disable paste entirely if the clipboard is empty, so pressing Shift+Ins wouldn't do anything at all, while with an active selection the result would be different if you did with an empty string in the clipboard.

Comment: Thanks, @millimoose. I've used this for my own purpose - empty String works for my cases and I guess for most. Not a hack IMO.

Comment: @millimoose It has the desired effect actually. The `DataFlavors` and `transferData` are not null.

Comment: @Joey I understand the distinction, I'm just saying that a hack like this might not necessarily be an invalid solution. I.e. the requirement on the resulting clipboard state might not be "no data of any flavour is available", but "it is impossible to retrieve the data that was available previously". Say if you're implementing a password manager and this is a security feature, both work equally fine.

Comment: @millimoose, granted. The solution I found came from a testing direction where it makes a lot more sense to *actually* clear the clipboard to test disabling of certain GUI parts properly. I didn't think of doing that just to remove the previous value. Although I think for a password manager it makes a lot more sense to never place the data directly in the clipboard but rather in a way where your password manager is queried instead, so that you remain in control of the data.